# Gstreamer: gst-launch ICYDEMUX output as textoverlay

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, gst-launch

I am trying to use gst-launch to extract radio metadata and textoverlay onto video/goom visualization.I am stuck at the overlay part.

Hope someone can give me some pointers on how to do this, GStreamer is too complex even for ChatGPT.

Please see image below, as the popup window is able to extract the metadata from radio station.

[Gstreamer ICYDEMUX GOOM TextOverlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpR5y.png)

Here is my test command line;

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/NOVA_969_AAC48.aac?src=digitalradioplus-com-au ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! goom ! textoverlay halignment=center valignment=bottom text="SONG INFO GOES HERE" shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 36" ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600 ! autovideosink
```

Following code just shows the metadata as songs change on the radio;

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/NOVA_969_AAC48.aac?src=digitalradioplus-com-au ! icydemux ! fakesink -t
```

I need to inject the metadata output into the textoverlay in the test command line.
Any idea on hoow to do this using gst-launch only?